# Function quote_nullable(timestamp without time zone) is not unique

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, datatypes, functions, enterprisedb

When I run this query on "enterprisedb 9.2", it raises an error:

```
select quote_nullable(to_date('09-02-2014 ','dd-MM-yyyy'))::date;
```

Error:

> ```
> LINE 1: select quote_nullable(to_date('09-02-2014 ','dd-MM-yyyy'))::...
>                ^
> HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: function quote_nullable(timestamp without time zone) is not unique
> SQL state: 42725
> Hint: Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.
> Character: 8
> ```

In Postgresql 9.1, this query above run ok.

Please tell me what is happening here. Why is the function `quote_nullable(timestamp without time zone)` not unique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works as is in my installation (Postgres 9.3).

You probably can fix this by casting to `text`.

```
SELECT quote_nullable(to_date('09-02-2014 ','dd-MM-yyyy')::text);
```

And do **not** cast the result to `date`. It  would be pointless to call `quote_nullable()` if you try to cast the result back to `date`. It would also fail for NULL input.

Postgres allows [function overloading](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xfunc-overload.html). My installation has one instance of [`quote_nullable()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) taking `text` and another one taking `anyelement` ([polymorphic type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xfunc-sql.html#AEN52059)). The latter takes care of the `date`.

As for `timestamp without time zone`: Postgres first looks for an exact match (`date` in your case), then considers other options like types that can be cast implicitly or polymorphic types. The manual has the exact procedure for [Function Type Resolution.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/typeconv-func.html)

Not sure about EnterpriseDB. Run this to diagnose:

```
SELECT n.nspname AS schema_name
      ,p.proname AS function_name
      ,pg_get_function_arguments(p.oid) AS args
      ,pg_get_functiondef(p.oid) AS func_def
FROM   pg_proc p
JOIN   pg_namespace n ON n.oid = p.pronamespace
WHERE  proname = 'quote_nullable';
```

More about function overloading in this related answer on SO:
[ERROR: function addgeometrycolumn is not unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12331981/error-function-addgeometrycolumn-is-not-unique/12332355#12332355)

Comment: @Er Brand: thanks, I run "SELECT quote_nullable(to_date('09-02-2014 ','dd-MM-yyyy'))::text;" in Enterprisedb 9.2, I still get error. And with your second query it return two rows (quote_nullabe: anyelement, text) .

Comment: @luannnh: Sorry, my mistake. The cast needs to go after the first closing parenthesis. Consider updated answer. Would have been an "impossible" diagnosis otherwise. The error message is still odd.

Comment: @Er Brand: it's ok . But when I run "select quote_nullable(to_date('09-02-2014 ','dd-MM-yyyy'))::date;" in POSTGRESQL, it work fine ^^! (but in EDB it get error) . Could you explain me this problem, please ?

Comment: @luannnh: Sorry, I don't work with EnterpriseDB directly. The different behavior is puzzling me, too, since you seem to have the same two functions. Did you get it to work, then?

Comment: @Er Brand: Until now, I don't clearly know about my problem. I think this is a EDB's bug. I will use another function (same quote_nullable). Thanks a gain Mr ERwin Brandstetter.