# Make query depend on input in PostgreSQL function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, parameter

I have a simple query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION companies_all_teams(
  IN  _company_name text = NULL,
  IN  _company_id int = NULL,
  OUT _result text
)
AS
$$
  BEGIN
  _result := (SELECT json_agg(distinct(teams.name))
                     FROM jobs
                     JOIN companies
                       ON companies.id = jobs.company_id
                     JOIN teams
                       ON teams.id = jobs.team_id
                     WHERE lower(companies.name) = lower(_company_name)
                       AND jobs.is_disabled = false
             );
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

There are two inputs, but only one of those is being used in the query. What is the simplest way to run the query conditionally based on which input we have?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for pointing out. It was typo. I have fixed it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can sometimes provide `_company_id` directly, while you only have `_company_name` in other situations. You do *not* intend to provide *both* at once.

Since one parameter is of type `text` while the other is `integer` the most efficient solution for this case is probably **[function overloading](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xfunc-overload.html)**. I.e., create **two functions** of the same name, one for `text` and another one for `integer`.

While being at it, I suggest simple SQL functions for the simple task. The principal is the same as for plpgsql.

`json_agg()` returns data type `json`, not `text`. Your plpgsql variant silently coerces the type in the assignment, but that's bad style. I made out the functions to return `json` directly. You can cast to `text` explicitly if you need to.

#### 1) `companies_all_teams(text)`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION companies_all_teams(_company_name text)
  RETURNS json AS
$func$
   SELECT json_agg(DISTINCT(t.name))
   FROM   companies c
   JOIN   jobs      j ON j.company_id = c.id
   JOIN   teams     t ON t.id = j.team_id
   WHERE  lower(c.name) = lower(_company_name)
   AND    NOT j.is_disabled
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

#### 2) `companies_all_teams(int)`

Since we have two functions, we can optimize each for their input. Assuming referential integrity in your relational design, we don't need to join to `companies` at all, we already know the `company_id`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION companies_all_teams(_company_id int)
  RETURNS json AS
$func$
   SELECT json_agg(DISTINCT(t.name))
   FROM   jobs      j
   JOIN   teams     t ON t.id = j.team_id
   WHERE  j.company_id = _company_id
   AND    NOT j.is_disabled
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

To avoid ambiguity with overloaded function calls you need to provide explicitly typed values. In your simple case, however, it's still enough to use **[numeric literals](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS)** (no single quotes) for `integer` or **[string literals](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS)** (single quotes) for `text`.

Call:

```
SELECT companies_all_teams(123);           -- numeric literal without quotes
SELECT companies_all_teams('My Company');  -- string literal with quotes
```

Related:

- [No function matches the given name and argument types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24771122/939860)
- [Function quote_nullable(timestamp without time zone) is not unique](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60704/function-quote-nullabletimestamp-without-time-zone-is-not-unique/60705#60705)
- [Is there a way to disable function overloading in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28710225/939860)