# How to pass an array to a plpgsql function with VARIADIC parameter

Tags: postgresql, functions, plpgsql, array, parameter

I am trying to define a plpgsql function in Postgresql 10 with several parameters, including an array.

I have already defined the function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mix_table_fields(input_table_name VARCHAR, output_table_name VARCHAR, VARIADIC field_names VARCHAR[])
[...]
```

Now, when I try to call it:

```
SELECT mix_table_fields('articles'::VARCHAR, 'output_random_articles'::VARCHAR, array['type'::varchar,'colour'::varchar,'size'::varchar,'price'::varchar]) ;
```

I get the following error : " *the function mix_table_fields(character varying, character varying, character varying[]) does not exist*".

I have had this error before. It cannot recognize the signature of the function (its input parameters).

When I use pgAdmin3 to look at the function definition, it is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.mix_table_fields(
    IN input_table_name character varying,
    IN output_table_name character varying,
    VARIADIC field_names character varying[])
```

I cannot see what's wrong.

And if there is a way of getting rid of the `::VARCHAR` at each parameter when calling the function, it would be easier.

Answer (score 4):

To pass an actual ***array*** for a `VARIADIC` parameter, you must use the keyword **`VARIADIC` in the call**:

```
SELECT mix_table_fields('art'::VARCHAR
                      , 'out'::VARCHAR
                      , VARIADIC array['type'::varchar,'colour'::varchar,'size'::varchar,'price'::varchar]);
```

Even works **without explicit type casts** in your case. [Function type resolution](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv-func.html) finds the best match as long as there is no [overloaded](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-overload.html) variant only differing in (also compatible) parameter types. Call with array literal:

```
SELECT mix_table_fields('art', 'out', VARIADIC '{type,colour,size,price}');
```

Without the keyword `VARIADIC`, Postgres expects a ***list*** of element values like:

```
SELECT mix_table_fields('art', 'out', 'type', 'colour', 'size', 'price');
```

... which is the whole point of a `VARIADIC` function parameter: to be able to call it with a variable number of parameters of the *element type*. (Also the reason why a `VARIADIC` parameter must come last in the parameter list: else the call could be ambiguous.) If you don't need this feature, use a plain `varchar[]` parameter without `VARIADIC` in the function definition to begin with.

Related:

- [How to use an array as argument to a VARIADIC function in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/158078/how-to-use-an-array-as-argument-to-a-variadic-function-in-postgresql/158088#158088)
- [Make query depend on input in PostgreSQL function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102270/make-query-depend-on-input-in-postgresql-function/122365#122365)